# How to create a line of X length with AddLine

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I've been trying to create a line in excel using the [AddLine method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addline?view=excel-pia) of interop. However, I've not been able to succesfully configure the line how I want it. The line is roughly in the spot I would like it to be, but setting the length is a mystery to me. Following my code:

```
        Shape line = worksheet.Shapes.AddLine(50, 100, 500, 100);  //length = 450 points
        Range startcell = worksheet.Cells[3, 7];
        line.Left = (float)startcell.Left;
        line.Top = (float)startcell.Top;
```

My worksheet has the line, but calculating the length using the amount of cells and their width in points or pixels does not match the coded length. The actual length is between 736 to 759 pixels or 51,2 to 52,8 points.

Edit:
I have found via [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347279/6787751) that the points unit has 2 measurements. I get the following:

```
ColumnWidth = 1,6           column is 1,6 characters wide 
Width = 13,8                column is 13,8 points wide 
Height = 13,8
```

This gives me an actual line length between 524,4 and 538,2 points. This still doesn't match my coded 450 points.

My question being: How can I make my line exactly as long (and in position) as I want it to be?
Related/including: The measurement in c# is in points, does this match the points as shown in the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My edit actually is the answer. I forgot to substract 81,6 points of the preceding cells (6 * 13,8 = 81,6).
That means that the points unit used in AddLine() is the same as the Cell.Width and Cell.Height property unit, which is not shown in the Excel GUI.